# Raw export Twilio Studio execution logs and debugger messages?

Tags: twilio

Is there a way to programmatically export Twilio Studio execution logs and debugger messages? (JSON) I'd be looking to ingest this into our log aggregator in order to use our integrated alerting system.

(p.s. I know it's possible to [raw-export SMS and Call logs](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183588-Exporting-SMS-and-Call-Logs), but it's too granular. I'm looking for Studio execution logs so I can diagnose problems at each step of the flow.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. The Studio Flow execution logs are available in this [API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/v2/step-context)

Sample Python 3 code:

```python
executions = client.studio.flows(flow_sid).executions.list()
steplist = [list(reversed([(x.name, x.step_context().fetch().context) 
                           for x in exec.steps.list()])) 
            for exec in executions]
```

Answer (score 0):

Studio - REST API v2

https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/v2

> With the Studio REST API you can trigger Flows programmatically for
> outbound use cases, manage Flow definitions for automated deployments,
> and retrieve information about Executions for reporting.

Comment: Could you expand on the link? I'm not sure I'm seeing the answer -- I'd like to be able to programmatically raw export Studio execution logs and debugger logs.

Right now, I can only view the logs through Twilio's web interface, but this does not help me integrate them with my own log aggregator.

Thanks for your help.